# react redux - how to reload the page instead of "push"

Tags: reactjs, redux, connected-react-router

I have a thunk action  that logout the user

inside the logout thunk action I have this:    `dispatch(push('/login'));`

I would like to redirect the user with a "refresh" to logout in order to refresh the page and. "clean' the state

also, I would like to clean the redux store, and not its not clean

```
import { push } from 'connected-react-router';


export function logout() {
  return async (dispatch: any, state: State, services: Services) => {
    try {
        await services.auth.logout();
    } catch (e) {
      services.logger.error(e);
    } finally {
      dispatch({ type: AUTH_LOGOUT });
      dispatch(push('/login'));
    }
  };
}
```

also when click on a button from component I have

```
const Logout = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(logout());
  }, [dispatch]);

  return null;
};
```

Reducer

```
   case AUTH_LOGOUT: {
        draft.authenticated = false;
        draft.currentUser = {} ;
        return draft;
      }
```

Comment: you can use window.location.reload() to reload the page after logout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you can simply do `window.location.href = '/login';`

Comment: also, I would like to clean the redux store, and not its not clean
how do I change the routing state?

     case AUTH_LOGOUT: {
        draft.authenticated = false;
        draft.currentUser = {} ;
        return draft;
      }

this my reduer

Comment: the code I gave you will trigger a full page refresh and the state should clean-up in the process

Answer (score 0):

React automatically reloads when you change a state. So you need to change a state. For example a login/logout flag or an authorization flag you have used.
From Your code, you need to change it where you have defined your case for AUTH_LOGOUT in your reducer.

Comment: How do  I change the state?

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript's window object for refresh.
`e.g., window.location.href = "router_address"`